# 0000-00-00 Date in Axis

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, axis

I have the following task:

I have to build a masive WS client with over 400 methods and very complex requests and responses, i am using axis 1.4, the WS is on a legacy system that i can not change.

The problem I'm facing is the responses for some of the methods contains the date: "0000-00-00" when the field is not filled.

```
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid date
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:180) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384) [axis-1.4.jar:]
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467) [axis-1.4.jar:]
```

I have managed to get it working by manually changing the fields into String and formating them to Date when needed, but in my opinion that is not an elegant solution.

Does anyone know how can I do this better.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not use NULL istead of 0000-00-00 since you're only using 0000-00-00 for when a value is not set? You can then make adjustments to your components that are showing the value so they are showing what you want it to say when there are no value. It is hard to say anything more since your description of what you're trying to do is very vague.

Comment: I'm building the client, I have no control on the data that comes from the server, I have to adapt my code to replace the 0000-00-00 date with null to be compatible with java, without overriding the axis serialization mechanism.